# Print Emoji on PDF in Android

Tags: java, android, pdf-generation, emoji

I have requirement to export pdf from local database, And I have done this for image and text it work perfect, but I want to print emoji on a PDF and I don't know how. If anyone has an idea, please reply. For PDF export I am using [iTextPDF](http://itextpdf.com/) and for Emoji [Emojicon](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon).

Comment: Please show us some code. What does Emojicon produce? Does it produce a font program? an image? `Graphics2D` (note that `Graphics2D` isn't supported on Android)? Currently, your question requires to much work from anyone who wants to answer it. You have to help the people who want to help you by explaining what Emojicon is about (we are not going to read the Emojicon code to find out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use https://github.com/pepibumur/emojize for add emojis to your project. There are methods for parsing or sth:

```
public static String emojiText(String text){}
public static String demojizedText(String text){}
```

There are emoji graphics and apis https://github.com/arvida/emoji-cheat-sheet.com

Comment: first link is not found.

Comment: Due to the dead link, this answer is outdated as of 2022.